# How to dump contents of a Java library to the console?

Tags: java, scala, command-line, console

Is there a tool for dumping the contents of a library or [JAR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_file) file to the console?

I'm looking for the Java counterpart of `DUMPBIN /SYMBOLS`, which works on Windows native-mode libaries. With C# and the rest of .NET, there are a bunch of visual tools like [.NET Reflector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Reflector)  and the object browsers built into Visual Studio. All-in-all, I prefer command-line tools, but I will be grateful anything that works :)

(I'm just getting started with Java and Scala on Windows.)

Comment: What exactly are trying to accomplish? Perhaps it's my isolation on the JVM and scripting languages talking here, but why would you ever need to do this?

Comment: For the same reason that you say "dir" or "ls -l" when you go to a directory. To see what's in there, get a feel for how things might fit together, to see some names you might not have noticed (serendipity), for discovery, overview, guided exploration. For the same reason that you look at a map of a city when you get there, even though it doesn't tell you every detail about the buildings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can unpack a JAR file (`jar xf my.jar`) to see the contents; if you want to do this within your code, there are tools in `java.util.jar` for working with JAR fileS.

Alternatively, if you know part of the package hierarchy, you can type part of it in the Scala [REPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read-eval-print_loop) and hit tab to get a list of valid completions. For example:

```
scala> java.util.jar.   <-- hit tab here
Attributes              JarEntry                JarException            
JarFile                 JarInputStream          JarOutputStream         
JarVerifier             JavaUtilJarAccessImpl   Manifest                
Pack200
```

However, it's awfully hard to figure out how to use things without API documentation. Your first step should almost always be to try to find the documentation and look at them instead.

Comment: There's also the `:javap -v <Class>` command in the Scala REPL, which shows the JVM bytecode for a named class.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I want the list just as a reminder of exact name with spelling, and to get a rough overview. Just as when I cd or pushd to some directory, I often go "ls -l" or "dir". The result doesn't tell me what's in the files -- it has no semantic depth, it just reminds me what's there and gives me an overall overview frame to refresh my memory on how the entire contents fit together.

Answer (score 11):

The command you're looking for is:

`jar tf <jarfilename>`

Answer (score 3):

If you know the class name:

```
$ javap -classpath jarfile some.package.in.that.jarfile.ClassName
```

Also you can "script-ize" it so that it iterates through all the classes in the jar file and run javap for each one

Answer (score 1):

Also note that a JAR file is merely just a zipped file so any [ZIP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_%28file_format%29) utility would do. And most IDEs offer to explore inside the JAR libraries you add to a project ([Eclipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29) for instance).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, JAR files are ZIP files and can be extracted in the same way.

To browse the classes inside a JAR file, I recommend you to use an IDE. Add the JAR file as a library dependency to your project, and then you should be able to browse through the classes and methods.

How about obtaining the source code for the JAR file (if that's possible)?